# Will it be alright if I put a multithreaded (OMP) job and a multiprocess (MPI) job together on the same node (2 cpu sockets)?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmp, job-scheduling

I am using a Linux HPC server and am kind of the manager.

Recently one of the users ran a multithreaded job using OpenMP.
All jobs are supposed to be submitted through the scheduler (SunGridEngine, SGE). One user submited a multi-process (MP) job and another user submited a multi-threaded (MTH) job.

For the MP job, CPUs are assigned at the scheduling stage so there is no problem at all. But I wonder how CPUs are assigned for the MTH job. And I am worried if a CPU occupied by the MTH job will interrupt the CPU used by the MP job.

Will it be alright? If not, how can I manage this situation?

FYI:
Sometimes, the load exceeds the number of CPU cores when using MTH.
So I tried to set the number of threads (limit) at the level of OMP coding. But the load (CPU %) frequently exceeds CPU load a little bit.

Comment: If this will work out automatically depends on how SGE manages resources. OpenMP threads can be bound to cores using e.g. the [`OMP_PLACES`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse53.html) environment variable.

Comment: Ideally OMP pragmas will leave the number of threads up to the [`OMP_NUM_THREADS`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse50.html) environment variable so it can be set at runtime (e.g. by the scheduler) but in practice many people hard-code the number of threads so one cannot rely on that.

Comment: @paleonix people who don't know the good practices do that, but in a HPC center some directives can be sent to the users to remind them the good practices, with some penalties (e.g. denying access) to users who repeatedly override the rules. But yeah, the scheduler should set appropriate OMP_PLACES and OMP_PROC_BIND env variables to confine OpenMP jobs to selected physical cores, whatever the number of threads that are spawned.

Comment: I really appreciate your grammar correction on my question, @paleonix. I think 'bound to cores' must work. Thank you !